# UDP Server in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, udp

Need to establish a UDP server in Java for a vehicle tracking system.

Notice that [DatagramSocket](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive%28java.net.DatagramPacket%29) has a recieve method that block the program execution until a datagram is received.

I've noticed that there is a library [Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) that supposedly manages threads for an UDP server.

I want to avoid at all costs starting a multithreaded program, because that's kind of advanced programming.

Handling HTTP requests is tipically done with a Servlet, Isn't out there a established solution to manage UDP datagrams?

What about just making a synchronous (one threaded) program for this case?

Comment: Look at the `nio` library.  You'll have to write your own event loop and dispatch code, but from there it should feel similar to servlet programming.

Comment: I would start with a simple single threaded blocking loop. You can always do it more efficiently, if it turns out it's necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use Kryonet?

Comment: @jacktrades KryoNet has bunch of additional functionality which might be useful or might just complicate things. Tool/library recommendations are out of topic here.

Comment: You'll find that anything involving NIO is much more advanced than thread programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious choice to establish a UDP or TCP server in Java is [Netty](http://netty.io/)

It can act as a tcp/udp server and a client, it has both functionalities. Netty uses NIO.

> It greatly simplifies and streamlines network programming such as TCP
>   and UDP socket server.

It can also be used as a http server as well.